Dism /Apply-Image progress bar is delayed when executed
I am attempting to apply a .wim image of about 10GBs. (via Windows 11 bootable PE media)
This is the current command line I am executing: (via .HTA script)
DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:<path_to_image_file> /ApplyDir:<target_directory> /Index:< image_index> /CheckIntegrity /Verify
The command is executed and applies the .wim image onto the desired directory just fine.
However, I am unsure why there is a delay when displaying the progress bar for the /apply-image command.
During my install attempts, command prompt executes and displayed the below message:
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version : 10.0.22000.1 (with no progress bar only blinking cursor)
Then after about 5-6 minutes it finally displays the following progress bar:
Applying Image
[               1.0%              ]
On top of that when the progress bar reaches 79% it just jumps to 100%.
This is an issue I need to solve since this .wim image is going to be distributed to other users and will be accompanied by various scripts to automate the install for them. I do not want the users to believe it hung up.
In addition, when I attempt to apply a "test" .wim image of about 400KB. There is no delay and the percentage does not jump.
This is how I originally captured the image using the following command:
DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:<path_to_image_file> /CaptureDir:<source_directory> /Name:<image_name> /CheckIntegrity /Verify

this is normal behavior on a 10GB image. You might be able to fasten up the process a little by removing the integrity check. If you open taskmanager, you'll see what happens when DISM starts. Concider to use the /ScratchDir option as well
